# call function with the same parameters when run if

Tags: javascript, timer

```
function drawCountDown(date, path){
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = Date.parse(date); 

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

        // Output the result in an element with id="clock"
        document.getElementById(path).innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            drawCountDown(date, path);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

drawCountDown(darw_date[0], "euro-millions-timer");
drawCountDown(darw_date[1], "euro-millions-timer2");
```

Hello, 
I have this function the count down to event I have (I get this date from api). I have couple events that happens couple of time during the week and I need to call the function every time the event is over to start count again.

I wrote if statement but I don't know if I can call the function again with the same parameters for the event specific.

you can see the last two lines- every one of them give other time for different events and I want to call the function when she stop count again with the same parameters individual.

can't figure how to do that. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking if you can ? as one could say, "Just do it". You can always try. BTW, you will end in an endless loop if you do recursion inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: I know I can do it. but I can figure how.
I will call the function again only when she arrived to 0 so why I will get endless loop?

Comment: I don't get it: you want to print a counter decreasing every second ? if so, why do you have recursion ? if `distance` gets positive, stop the interval with the `clearInterval()` method.

Comment: I have event the happen every Monday and Friday at the same time.
when the counter arrived to Monday I need him to start count for Friday.

then I have other event that happen every Sunday and Wednesday so I need that the counter count to Wednesday and that to Sunday and than to Wednesday again.